# Converting Dos Text Files to Unix in VBA fails

Tags: vba, excel

I've followed the suggestion in a prior question and grabbed this code but I don't get a useable file out of it. I've looked at it and don't see the problem.

```
    Public Enum ConvertType
dos2unix = 0
unix2dos = 1
    End Enum

    Public Function ConvertFile(OriginalFile As String, NewFile As String, eConvertType As ConvertType, _
                        Optional DeleteOriginal As Boolean = False)

Dim OpenFileNum, SaveFileNum As Integer
Dim NewFileBuffer As String


' This function will open a file and convert it to
' a txt file format usable under *nix or dos
On Error GoTo Error_Found

OpenFileNum = FreeFile ' grab the first free file
Open OriginalFile For Input As #OpenFileNum ' open the unix file
    SaveFileNum = FreeFile ' get another free file to write to
    Open NewFile For Binary As #SaveFileNum ' open/create the save file
        Do While Not EOF(OpenFileNum)
            Line Input #OpenFileNum, NewFileBuffer ' retrive the text (if a unix file, then the entire text is on one line)
            If eConvertType = dos2unix Then ' Check what type of conversion to do
                NewFileBuffer = NewFileBuffer & Chr(10)
            Else
                NewFileBuffer = Replace(NewFileBuffer, Chr(10), vbCrLf)
            End If
            Put #SaveFileNum, , NewFileBuffer ' write out the file
        Loop
    Close #SaveFileNum
Close #OpenFileNum

If DeleteOriginal = True Then Kill OriginalFile

    Exit_Sub:
    Exit Function
```

Comment: We need more info to be able to help. What do you mean you don't get a usable file? What are you looking to get? What are you trying to achieve? What have you tried?

Comment: I feed a dos text file in and need a unix text file out. But all I get is a mess of garbage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub testConversion()
    convertFile "C:\test.txt"
End Sub

Public Sub convertFile(ByVal fileName As String)
    Const Dos2Unix = 1
    Dim fs As Object, txt As String
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    txt = fs.OpenTextFile(fileName, 1).ReadAll  'ForReading = 1
    txt = IIf(Dos2Unix = 1, Replace(txt, vbCrLf, vbLf), Replace(txt, vbLf, vbCrLf))
    fs.OpenTextFile(fileName, 2).Write txt      'ForWriting = 2
End Sub
```

Notes:

- In Notepad (Windows) all lines will appear on one continuous line
- All CarriageReturn–Linefeed combinations are replaced by Linefeed characters

Comment: I still get what look like Chinese characters back. Like this: 潚敮›彺桤瑰㑧户㙟搱ㄱ㙶〱㕳㥰娊湯⁥敍扭牥›〵〺㨶戰〺㨰〰㈺㨵ㄲ

Comment: I tested the code with a normal text file, your file might be in a different format, so try the following, and I'll update the answer with what works for you. After the line `txt = fs.OpenTextFile...` place the following line: `txt = StrConv(txt, vbUnicode)`, test it, if it doesn't work replace `vbUnicode` with `vbFromUnicode`, or `vbWide`, or `vbNarrow`

Comment: Thanks for the help Paul, but none of those worked on the file I have.  It's a terminal capture from a cisco fiber channel switch so there may be control chars messing things up.

Comment: Just for the record, it wasn't the original file. It was a bad output from powershell. (Doh!)